# How to deserialize gui objects in java

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, clickable

I have grid of JPanels that is clickable and can change the color of each panel. I have two buttons store and restore to save and retrieve objects. In the attached screenshot, I have selected first row, second column and store it to a file. I have tried to select the first row, third column and click restore button to restore the previous saved data - which should be the first row, second column only selected. But it is not being restored as it seems.

Below is the code:

```
private class StoreRestoreButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == buttonStore) {
            if (textFileName.getText().equals("")) {
                labelCurrentStatus.setText("Please input the filename to store");
            } else {
                // Write display list array list to an object output stream.
                  try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(textFileName.getText());
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    //displayList is an ArrayList of objects
                    oos.writeObject(displayList);
                    oos.flush();
                    oos.close();
                    fos.close();
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                     labelCurrentStatus.setText("Error saving file");
                    System.err.println("Error saving file");
                  }
            }

        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonRestore) {
             if (textFileName.getText().equals("")) {
                 labelCurrentStatus.setText("Please input the filename to restore");
             } else {
                 // Read a new display list array list from an object input stream.
                  try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(textFileName.getText());
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                    //displayList is an ArrayList of Room objects
                    displayList = (ArrayList<Room>) ois.readObject();
                    rebuildGridPanel(displayList);
                    ois.close();
                    fis.close();
                    repaint();
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println("Trouble reading file");
                    labelCurrentStatus.setText("Trouble reading file");
                  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
             }

        }

    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: And you don't see any errors?

Comment: Does your code from restore button execute? How does Room class looks like?

Comment: @Seitaridis yes the code from restore button execute. The Room class is just a pojo that includes all the data that I want to save. It has property like selectedPanel, that will save the name of the panel being selected. Does it mean that I need to manually reset all the  grids above?

Comment: @Einar no errors. I am not sure if the repaint() method will just repaint the jpanel grids?

Comment: Does Room class implements Serializable interface?

Comment: @Seitaridis yes it is implementing Serializable interface. And on the logs, I can see that everything got restored on "displayList". How can I restore it back to the user interface for each panel grids?